# How to make this Gauge differential angles?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a radial gauge for a dashboard. The following code is my work. 
I need to know how to make the starting angle of this to be 15 degrees and how to make the ending angle 165 degrees. Please help me with it. 
I need to implement this system so looking forward to getting this done. 
I also need to add the tick marks t this. How can I do it? I am trying to use Chart JavaScript for that so please guide me on how can i do it?

Regards.

```css
body {
  background: #fff;
  
}

#radial:before {
  background: yellowgreen;
  border-radius: 220px 220px 0 0;
  /* box-shadow: 3px 1px 8px rgba(2, 1, 1, 0.15) inset; */
  content: "";
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 350px;


}

#radial {
  border-radius: 400px 400px 0 0;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 50px auto 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  
}

#radial:after {
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-radius: 140px 140px 0 0;
  bottom: 0;
  box-shadow: 3px 1px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  /* color: rgba(255, 80, 0, 0.7); */
  content: "";
  font-family: Lato, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 3.5em;
  font-weight: 100;
  height: 70px;
  left: 30px;
  line-height: 95px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 140px;
  
}

#needle {
  background: radial-gradient(black, red);
  border-radius: 8px;
  bottom: -4px;
  /* box-shadow: 3px -1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4); */
  display: block;
  height: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  transform-origin: 100% 4px;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition:4s ;
  z-index: 2;
  /* border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px; */
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0%, 0% 50%, 100% 100% );
  
}

#radial:hover span {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

/* h1,
p,
strong {
  display: block;
  font-family: Lato;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  margin-bottom: 0.1em;
}

p {
  margin-top: 0;
}

strong {
  color: #be1e1e;
  font-size: 2.5em;
} */
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <tite></tite>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="GaugeCss_last.css">
        <!-- <script type="text/javascript"></script> -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
    </head>

    <head>
        
    </head>

    <body>
            <div id="radial" data-value="0">
            <span id="needle" value="8"></span>
            </div>
        
        
    </body>
    <script>

    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check may be you want this

```css
body {
  background: #fff;
  
}

#radial:before {
  background: yellowgreen;
  border-radius: 220px 220px 0 0;
  /* box-shadow: 3px 1px 8px rgba(2, 1, 1, 0.15) inset; */
  content: "";
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 350px;


}

#radial {
  border-radius: 400px 400px 0 0;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 50px auto 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  
}

#radial:after {
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-radius: 140px 140px 0 0;
  bottom: 0;
  box-shadow: 3px 1px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  /* color: rgba(255, 80, 0, 0.7); */
  content: "";
  font-family: Lato, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 3.5em;
  font-weight: 100;
  height: 70px;
  left: 30px;
  line-height: 95px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 140px;
  
}

#needle {
  background: radial-gradient(black, red);
  border-radius: 8px;
  bottom: -4px;
  /* box-shadow: 3px -1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4); */
  display: block;
  height: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  transform-origin: 100% 4px;
  transform: rotate(15deg);
  transition:4s ;
  z-index: 2;
  /* border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px; */
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0%, 0% 50%, 100% 100% );
  
}

#radial:hover span {
  transform: rotate(165deg);
}

/* h1,
p,
strong {
  display: block;
  font-family: Lato;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  margin-bottom: 0.1em;
}

p {
  margin-top: 0;
}

strong {
  color: #be1e1e;
  font-size: 2.5em;
} */
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <tite></tite>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="GaugeCss_last.css">
        <!-- <script type="text/javascript"></script> -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
    </head>

    <head>
        
    </head>

    <body>
            <div id="radial" data-value="0">
            <span id="needle" value="8"></span>
            </div>
        
        
    </body>
    <script>

    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change 2 things at your css

1 - for ID #needle

```
    transform: rotate(15deg);
```

2  - for hover #radial:hover span

```
transform: rotate(165deg);
```

Comment: Yes i tried that. It works perfectly. but what I want is to make the Green part the radial to stop and start in this level. then the needle can be done.

Comment: @AzezurRahman sorry but i didnt get this part  "I want is to make the Green part the radial to stop and start in this level"